# Sharepoint SPGridView Filtering with Lookup fields

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SPGridView that displays items from a list with filtering.

the list has some lookupfields.
in my SPGridview the filter values of a lookupfield appear in this format:

```
{id};#{Value}
```

which makes the filter not work because it is expecting the value only without the {id};#

is there a way to display the filter values without the {id};# part ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved this issue:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Campaign Members">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# RemoveCharacters(Eval("CampaignMembers").ToString())%> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

// Make sure declare using System.Text.RegularExpression; protected string 
RemoveCharacters(object String) 
{ 
    string s1 = String.ToString(); 
    string newString = Regex.Replace(s1, @"#[\d-];", string.Empty); 
    newString = Regex.Replace(newString, "#", " "); 
    return newString.ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the FilteredDataSourcePropertyFormat property to

```
"({1} LIKE '{0}') OR ({1} LIKE '{0};%') OR ({1} LIKE '%;#{0}') OR ({1} LIKE '%;#{0};%')"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you generating columns for SPGridView, use SPBoundField, not BoundField.